# Facebook Login Button - Click with casperjs/phantomjs dont work

Tags: javascript, facebook, phantomjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, casperjs

i try to test the facebook login with CasperJS, but when "click" no popup are shown in the screenshots.

But when i click manually in the browser it works.

```js
casper.then(function () {
    casper.waitForSelector('.fb-login-button iframe', function () {
    casper.capture('facebook_button_shown.png');   
    casper.click('#facebookTriggerButton');

    casper.wait(1000, function() {
       casper.capture('popup_shown.png');   
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="facebookTriggerButton" class="fb-login-button"
     data-scope="public_profile, email"
     data-max-rows="1"
     data-size="xlarge"
     onlogin="checkStatus()"></div>
```

Comment: why would you want to test facebook login? what for exactly? i assume it´s intended that you cannot do it with casperjs.

Comment: Because i want an automatic test for the facebook login (OAuth) process.

Comment: that´s what test users are for, you should not do that with real ones.

Comment: i dont understand, can u explain what you mean? I use test user facebook accounts, but my Test in Casperjs dont work

Comment: that is what i mean: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users